# Int Primary key - exceeding int range

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-design

Just wondering what actually happens after you exceed 2147483647 records?

Comment: Would be easy to test - create an IDENTITY column seeded at 2147483646 and then add two records! :-)

Comment: Roll over and go for the negative series.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try it out

```
CREATE TABLE #tester (
    testerid INT IDENTITY(1, 1) not null CONSTRAINT pk_tester 
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED)

DBCC checkident(#tester, reseed, 2147483647)

INSERT #tester DEFAULT VALUES 
INSERT #tester DEFAULT VALUES
```

Msg 8115, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Arithmetic overflow error converting IDENTITY to data type int.

See also [What To Do When Your Identity Column Maxes Out](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBAdmin/MSSQLServerAdmin/what-to-do-when-your-identity-column-max) for a quick fix

Answer (score 1):

Most people forget there is a negative side to int which is one bigger than the positive side.  If you think you might outrun the positive int values just start your identity at the negative end of the range -2,147,483,648.  Or to really play with new DBA start at 2,147,483,647 and step by -1.

Answer (score 1):

If you think that is likely then use a datatype with a larger range. NUMERIC or BIGINT for example.